# CodeIgniter Form Validation is not allowing to save data nor showing any error

Tags: php, codeigniter, validation

I am new in CI and working on `form_validation` .
Everything is working fine but problem is, when I apply form validation on my code, it doesn't save the data into database nor shows any error. kindly guide me why this is happening.
I have loaded `form_validation` , `form` and `url` in autoload file.

**NOTE : When I remove validation, it saves the data in db, but doesn't after adding validation**

autoload.php

```
$autoload['libraries'] = array('database', 'email', 'session', 'form_validation');
$autoload['helper'] = array('url', 'file','form','site','index');
```

In My Controller

```
$this->form_validation->set_rules('name', 'Name', 'trim|required|xss_clean');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('email', 'Email', 'trim|required|xss_clean');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('phone', 'Phone', 'trim|required|xss_clean');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('mesg', 'Mesg', 'trim|required|xss_clean');

        if ($this->form_validation->run() == TRUE){

        $data = array(
        'name' => $this->input->post('name'),
        'email' => $this->input->post('email'),
        'phone' => $this->input->post('phone'),
        'mesg' => $this->input->post('mesg')
);

$this->db->insert('table_name', $data);

        redirect('feedback');

    } else {

        redirect('feedback');
    }
```

and in views file.

```
<?php echo validation_errors(); ?>


     <form name="" action="to_controller" method="post">

     <input type="text" class="form-control" required name="name">
     <input type="email" class="form-control" required name="email">
    <input type="number" min="0" class="form-control" required name="phone" >
    <textarea class="form-control" required name="mesg"></textarea>

    <button class="btn theme-btn full-width" type="submit">Send </button>
      </form>
```

Comment: which version of ci are you using

Comment: CI version *3.1.7*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

xss_clean is no longer part of form validation. The alternative is not to use it, as xss_clean is doing sanitization and not validation.

xss_clean is part of security helper. If you need to do it, after validation you do a:

```
$this->load->helper('security');
$value = $this->input->post('formvalue', TRUE);
```

// ...where TRUE enables the xss filtering

... i think...

Also, you can enable global xss filtering in the config.php file:

```
$config['global_xss_filtering'] = TRUE;
```

hope this helps you

Comment: it's working .. but special characters e.g ( . ? / : ') are still going to db ... i do want to exclude these characters using CI validation.

Comment: use `mysqli_real_escape_string();` to escape the special  character to go into db. Do switch the green tick when something better is posted: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/62252/is-it-poor-form-to-switch-accepted-answers

Comment: Coffee, there is a huge difference between validation and sanitation. Also, use html_escape for special characters. Look it up in the help